# How many characters are in RSA SSH public key?

Tags: rsa, calculation, public-key, string-length

In the Linux terminal, I am generating an RSA key as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024
```

I expect to get a public key consisting of 1024 bits.
when I show the public key using this command:

```
cat id_rsa.pub
```

I get something similar to the following:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA*********************== salar@salar-Dell-G15-5511
```

I am trying to see how many letters are in this public key, for that, I am using the Python function len() as follows:

```
print(len(key))
```

i got **238**

I wonder how is that possible.
i know that this public key is in characters, not bits but anyway how is the calculation done?

How can i get the length of generated public key accurately?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sed  "s/^\S* //;s/ .*//" | wc -m`

Answer (score 2):

- The bit count relates to the size of the private key, not the public key, so you're looking at the wrong file.
- The content of the private key file is a binary value that is encoded using base64, which results in a size increase of [around 33%](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-base64-encoding).

  (The public key content is also base64-encoded, and you can read some about the format [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-ssh-public-key-format/).)
- If we look at the private key, we see something like:

  ```
  -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
  NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAIEAwpop8Rm6pMjdoD6z/w1Z43r0VJ1E58nTOqgY28x38gIKLfbKgNL9
  [...]
  QQDDB9nNsP8qigJgfcwehPnTaoIa03CZwu4UH1BsK0DixB2YrduKQKokKvzttModGupw+T
  DPjRuvwQFJKfMl0FknAAAADmxhcnNAbWFkaGF0dGVyAQIDBA==
  -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  ```
- If we base64 decode that, it's 718 bytes (or 5744 bits).
- The private key isn't just "the key"; it contains [other data as well](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/).

If you wanted to confirm the private key length you would need to parse the content of the file and extract that particular information.

---

As for "verifying" a public key, a simple check is to base64-decode the key content and see if it starts with the same cipher name as the cleartext portion of the key.  That is, like this in Python:

```
import base64
import struct

with open('example.pub', 'rb') as fd:
    keytype, keyencoded, keyextra = fd.readlines()[0].split(None, maxsplit=2)

keydata = base64.b64decode(keyencoded)

# get the length of the first chunk of data
cipherlen = struct.unpack('>I', keydata[:4])[0]

# and read that data into a variable
encodedkeytype = keydata[4:cipherlen+4]

if keytype == encodedkeytype:
    print('valid key')
else:
    print('invalid key')
```

(This is a modified version of [this code](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2011-05-08-converting-openssh-public-keys/#openssh-public-key-format) that I wrote many, many years ago so no claims about its quality.)

Comment: I did not that -b 1024 is related to the private key, for now, I just want to know the number of characters in the public key file.
I want to know if the given string is a valid public key or not